# why does my tmux session gets killed for no reason?

Tags: session, ssh, tmux

I have one question that stops my work at the moment. I use tmux in order to run a python file at a remote computer. My Problem is the following: I run a script, I shut down my PC and also the SSH connection
The next day when I check my session it says "session killed". This happend for a few days in a row and none of my collegues killed it. So I wander if someone can name me some reasons to check if the improve the problem.

Some additional info:
My python file works fine, it is already tested for shorter runtime.
I already checked it it gets killed because of disconnecting the ssh connection. It does not get killed.

I hope someone knows more than me about tmux :)